# http post from lambda to ecs fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs

I have created a lambda function which gets fargate IP and port using cloudmap and then use the same ip and port for POST http request, i am able to get the correct ip and port of the ecs task also when testing with lambda function it shows success but when i check the ecs logs nothing appears.

I have configured Lambda with private vpc subnet same as that of ecs, all the permissions are given correctly to the lambda. Is there any way i can check why the ecs is not accepting the post request? Do i need any additional settings in vpc like endpoint?

Comment: Did you add an ECS security inbound rule with lambda security group?

Comment: @omuthu yes i have still doesnt work.